# tsc is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc

I am using node version 6.9.2 with npm version 5.4.2 on Windows7. I have installed typescript with the command `npm install typescript -g`.

However, when I run a demo file using command, `tsc`, I get an error:

```
"tsc is not recognized as an internal or external command".
```

Could anybody help? Other node modules get installed correctly and working fine. Not sure why typescript isn't working.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Install node version 6.11 and things work without any changes.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is likely that `tsc` is not in the system path.

First, check if `tsc` is installed correctly. Open `cmd.exe` and type the following.

```
%AppData%\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc --version
```

If there is a version log, then `tsc` is installed successfully.

The next thing is to add it in PATH. Write in `cmd.exe`

```
setx path "%path%;%AppData%\npm\node_modules\.bin\"
```

This should solve the issue.

However, if the first command did not log the version,

Check the install location using

```
npm list -g
```

If typescript appears in the output, copy the location to the PATH as

```
setx path "%path%;<--the tsc.exe path-->"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: after the `setx` command, I think you have to reopen a new `cmd.exe` window, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I just installed node version 6.11 and everything worked. Not sure what the issue was. Thank you.

Comment: I've got interesting thing here. I've installed typescript globally. Command %AppData%\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc --version says that tsc not found, but when I run %AppData%\npm\tsc --version, It works, I get version output. This later directory is in my PATH. Nevertheless, when I try to rum tsc from arbitratry directory I get 'command not recognized' error.

Answer (score 1):

Since you installed it globally and you had no error, I can assume that the installation succeeded.

To be sure, you can run this command `npm config get prefix`. It will output the path of the folder containing all packages installed globally by npm. I you go to the folder specified by the path, there is a `nodes_modules` subfolder. It should contain a typescript folder if the installation succeeded. Then copy the `path of the bin` of the typescript folder in your environment variable. You should label the path `tsc`.

Then you can use `tsc` in command line.

Comment: I just installed node version 6.11 and everything worked. Not sure what the issue was. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution in this website and it worked for me.

-> If you are on windows and getting this error "*'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command*."

**Solution**
-> add the following path **"C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm"** to the PATH variable replace **user** with your windows user.
-> Restart the System.

Reference:- https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/setup-typescript/