# Typescript command "tsc" undefined. Tried every known solution

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, typescript, npm

Welcome,
I can't run Typescript all my day. I use Visual Studio Code. What I am doing is installing TS globally:

```
$ npm install -g typescript
```

Then when I check it:

```
$ tsc
```

**I get that error in all cases:**

> bash: tsc: command not found

**To that time I have tried following solutions:**

1. Setting npm config:

`$ npm config set prefix /usr/local`

What I get after `npm root -g` is:

> C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\node_modules

2. Setting npm config by relative way to get (And I get it):

   > C:\usr\local\node_modules
3. Setting .bash_profile:

`export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH`

4. Setting .bashrc with PATH also...
5. Installing Typecript as dev dependency also don't work.
6. Other small solutions that I even don't remember.

Please for help. I can provide more information that you need - just say what.

Comment: Maybe you can consider the answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46687102/tsc-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/46697977#46697977

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tried every known solution

## Will definitely work:

- Uninstall nodejs
- Install nodejs (make sure you ask it to set `PATH` for you)
- `npm install typescript -g`