# How do I use local TypeScript with npm on an isolated file in a larger project?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have an Expo TypeScript project with some scratch TypeScript files that I would like to test by running `tsc` (and then `node` on the emitted JS). But doing so results in unexpected errors, and fails to report legitimate expected TS errors.

I have a (correctly, I believe) configured TypeScript locally installed with npm, as [confirmed by](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46688147/656912)

```
$ ./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --version
Version 3.5.3
```

but when I try use `tsc` on a TypeScript file I get unexpected errors, such as those listed below following execution of

```
npx tsc somefile.ts
```

Moreover, `tsc` (at least when invoked as above) fails to emit any expected errors or compiler warnings, such as should be generated from, for example

```
let foo: number = 5
foo = null
```

Nonetheless, the expected `_somefile.js` is generated and runs as expected (ignoring errors).

How do I get `tsc` to detect errors in my `.ts` file, and avoid having it report numerous errors in other modules associated with my project installation?

---

Output from `npx tsc somefile.ts`, abbreviated:

```
node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:40:15 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'FormData'.

40 declare class FormData {
                 ~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5353:11
    5353 interface FormData {
                   ~~~~~~~~
    'FormData' was also declared here.
  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5363:13
    5363 declare var FormData: {
                     ~~~~~~~~
    and here.

node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:85:5 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'body' must be of type 'BodyInit', but here has type 'string | ArrayBuffer | DataView | Int8Array | Uint8Array | Uint8ClampedArray | Int16Array | Uint16Array | Int32Array | Uint32Array | Float32Array | Float64Array | Blob | FormData'.

85     body?: BodyInit_;
       ~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:1413:5
    1413     body?: BodyInit | null;
             ~~~~
    'body' was also declared here.

node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:111:14 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'RequestInfo'.

111 declare type RequestInfo = Request | string;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:18568:6
    18568 type RequestInfo = Request | string;
               ~~~~~~~~~~~
    'RequestInfo' was also declared here.

node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:130:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'Response' must be of type '{ new (body?: BodyInit, init?: ResponseInit): Response; prototype: Response; error(): Response; redirect(url: string, status?: number): Response; }', but here has type '{ new (body?: string | ArrayBuffer | DataView | Int8Array | Uint8Array | Uint8ClampedArray | Int16Array | Uint16Array | Int32Array | Uint32Array | Float32Array | Float64Array | Blob | FormData, init?: ResponseInit): Response; prototype: Response; error: () => Response; redirect: (url: string, status?: number) => Res...'.

130 declare var Response: {
                ~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:12463:13
    12463 declare var Response: {
                      ~~~~~~~~
    'Response' was also declared here.

node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:253:14 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'XMLHttpRequestResponseType'.

253 declare type XMLHttpRequestResponseType = "" | "arraybuffer" | "blob" | "document" | "json" | "text";
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:18746:6
    18746 type XMLHttpRequestResponseType = "" | "arraybuffer" | "blob" | "document" | "json" | "text";
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'XMLHttpRequestResponseType' was also declared here.

[...]

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:18746:6 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'XMLHttpRequestResponseType'.

18746 type XMLHttpRequestResponseType = "" | "arraybuffer" | "blob" | "document" | "json" | "text";
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:253:14
    253 declare type XMLHttpRequestResponseType = "" | "arraybuffer" | "blob" | "document" | "json" | "text";
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'XMLHttpRequestResponseType' was also declared here.


Found 12 errors.
```

Contents of `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node", 
    "noEmit": true, 
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "strict": true 
  }
}
```

The dependences in `project.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^34.0.4",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.5",
    "native-base": "^2.13.4",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0"
  },
```

Comment: I also have a [related but distinct question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57482041/656912) about support for "running" TypeScript files from WebStorm.

Answer (score -1):

These errors occur because both React Native and the standard `dom` modules define the same types.

Delete whichever of those you aren't using.

Comment: So should my `project.json` have some of the dependences (added do OP) be pruned?

Comment: How do I do that. Removing `react` for example from my `project.json` still gives the errors.

Comment: This error comes from the TypeScript compiler, not npm.  You need to remove it from `lib` in `tsconfig.json`.