# How I "Run" a TypeScript file in WebStorm?

Tags: typescript, webstorm

In my WebStorm IDE, all `.js` (and `.jsx`) files in my project have an associated "Run" command, but this feature is absent from `.ts` (or `.tsx`) files.

I believe I have correctly configured my project for TypeScript, as I am able to at least run `tsc` from the command line ([with somewhat unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57481957/656912)), but am surprised that I can't simply do this from within the IDE.

Does WebStorm support single file TypeScript compilation and running? Does enabling this require some specific non-default configuration of the IDE?

Comment: `tsc` doesn't run TypeScript, it compiles it. is that what you are trying to do? Where would you run it? On node? That's what happens to JS files, right?

Comment: @JuanMendes Yes: compile (`tsc`) then run (`node`) = "Run" (as frontend IDE functionality on a perf with "Run" for `.js` files.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Running Typescript files directly is not supported, as they can't be run with Node.js. You have to either pre-compile your code with `tsc` and then invoke **Run** on the compiled `js` file, or use on-the-fly compilation with [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node):

- `npm install -D ts-node typescript`
- in **Node.js** run configuration, specify `--require ts-node/register` as **Node parameters**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I wouldn't have figured that out!

Comment: Is there a quick way to get from the output that produces for an error back to the appropriate line in my file? I see the file named (e.g. `file.ks(4,1)1 but the relevant code isn't repeated and there's no popup I can see to jump to the spot in source where the error was found.

Comment: With the answer from @bluelovers I was able to just click on a button. No need to create run configurations manually

Answer (score 10):

Run Configuration for TypeScript
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10841-run-configuration-for-typescript/

Comment: Easiest one so far. Just install and run the file.

Answer (score 2):

I used `npx ts-node .\file_name.ts` command to run a specified ts file.

Answer (score -1):

Webstorm,at the time of this answer has an integrated Typescript Compiler. What you should do is Navigate to the toolbar File -> New -> tsconfig.json file.

After which you can create your Typescript file the same way or via the terminal

After you write your code, right click and at the bottom of the cascading menu, Compile Typescript. Enjoy